# Hide images in between rotation (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css

I've created a timer that switches and loops between images.

I'm looking to create a pause in between the images in which nothing is shown.

So logo1 on for 15 seconds
hide images for 30 seconds
logo2 on for 15 seconds
and so on

This is what I've got so far.

Ideally, the hide would hide both DIVS

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box1 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    align-content: safe;
}
.brandlogo {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 500;
    left: 1100;
}
.box2 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: #545454;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400;
    left: 1000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1" id="art">
        <img class="brandlogo" id="image" src="logo1.png" width="100">
    </div>
    <div class="box box2" id="frameart">
        <img class="brandframe" id="frame" src="adframe2.png" width="300">. 
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
    var currentPos = 0;
    var images = ["logo1.png", "logo2.png", "logo3.png"]


    function timercount() {
        if (++currentPos >= images.length)
            currentPos = 0;

        image.src = images[currentPos];
    }

    setInterval(timercount, 3000);

    $("#art").show();

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $("#art").hide(); 
    }, 500);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You said what you wanted to do, but you didn't say what you have got so far.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know how it goes :)

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  var currentPos = 0;
  var images = ["logo1.png", "logo2.png", "logo3.png"]

  // jquery api on hide
  // https://api.jquery.com/hide/
  function hideArt() {
    $("#art").hide(30000, changeLogo); 
  }

  function changeLogo() {
    if (++currentPos >= images.length) {
      currentPos = 0;
    }
    
    image.src = images[currentPos];

    // restart loop
    loop();
  }

  function loop() {
    // setTimeout api
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout
    setTimeout(hideArt, 15000);
  }
 
  // start loop
  loop();

</script>
```